# How to redirect old react-router HashRouter (with the #) to BrowserRouter?

Tags: reactjs, nginx, react-router

We're replacing `react-router-dom`s `HashRouter` with `BrowserRouter` and would like to redirect old routes to the new ones.
I tagged `nginx` because I don't mind making redirects there. :)

So say we have an old route `/#/users` and `/#/users:id`: They should match and redirect to `/users` and `/users/:id`.

So far I tried (`react-router-dom v5.0.1`):

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route path='/users' component={UsersComponent} />
    <Route path='/users/:id' component={UsersDashComponent} />
  </Switch>
  <Redirect from='/#/users' to '/users' />
  <Redirect from='/#/users/:id' to='/users/:id' />
</Router>
```

The first route matches and redirects fine. The second one (with the `id`) is problematic. When I navigate to `/#/users/123` it redirects to `/users/:id`. It's replacing the actual `123` with `:id`.

Those are two examples of routes. We have more with params to redirect as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution:

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route path='/users' component={UsersComponent} />
    <Route path='/users/:id' component={UsersDashComponent} />
    <Route exact path='/' render={({ location }) => <Redirect to={location.hash.replace('#', '')} />} />
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

Only routes that have `/#` will match `/`. One could easily add a conditional if needed to render something on root.

Answer (score 6):

To be honest, none of these solutions worked for me really, I wanted to perform a redirect from all my previous routes to the new ones without `#`.

While the accepted answer should be fine for most cases, I'm also handling 404s, which would not really be caught by such redirect.

Ended up adding a guard interacting with React Router history before rendering my switch:

```
function App() {
  const history = useHistory()

  if (location.hash.startsWith('#/')) {
    history.push(location.hash.replace('#', '')) // or history.replace
  }

  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" exact component={ Home } />
      ...
      <Route path="*" component={ PageNotFound } />
    </Switch>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think for navigation you are using something like this,

```
<Link to="/#/users" />
<Link to="/#/users/123" />
```

As per [docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/HashRouter),

> A `<Router>` that uses the hash portion of the URL (i.e. window.location.hash) to keep your UI in sync with the URL.

When using `HashRouter` you don't need to prepend `#` manually React router automatically adds `#` in `URL`

So your routes must be,

```
import { HashRouter } from 'react-router-dom'


<HashRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path='/users' component={UsersComponent} />
    <Route exact path='/users/:id' component={UsersDashComponent} />
  </Switch>
</HashRouter>
```

And links should be,

```
<Link to="/users" />
<Link to="/users/123" />
```

Now coming to your question, how to replace `HashRouter` with `BrowserRouter`?

To do so you just need to do this,

```
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'


<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Redirect from='/#/users' to '/users' />
    <Redirect from='/#users/:id' to='/users/:id' />
    <Route exact path='/users' component={UsersComponent} />
    <Route exact path='/users/:id' component={UsersDashComponent} />
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

And your links should be same.

**Note:** Also have a look I have added `exact` to `route`, it will match the exact `path`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. However, I'm actually not using the `<Link>` at all. Users can access the old links with the hash on their bookmarks, email, other sites etc...

Comment: Ok so this is not a issue of react but ngnix itself.

Comment: @AlvMF1 I have updated my answer. Make sure you write `<Redirect>` first and then your actual `<Route>`.

Comment: No luck. Have you tried? I'm redirected only if the `<Redirect>` is outside of `<Switch>`, but like the question says, the parameter isn't. I get `:id` as the param...

Comment: I have not tried this, but the docs say this only - https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Redirect.md

Answer (score 0):

```
export const history = createBrowserHistory();

export const App: FC = () => {
   return (
     <Router history={history}>
       <Switch>
        <Route path="/settings" exact component={Settings} />
       </Switch>
     </Router>
  );
};


export const Settings : FC = () => {
   return (
      <HashRouter basename="/" hashType="noslash">
        <Switch>
              <Route path="/profile">
                <Profile />
              </Route>
       </Switch>
    </HashRouter>
  );
};

 import {history} from "./App.tsx";

 export const Profile : FC = () => {
      return (
        <Router history={history}>
           <Link to="/product/1"/>
        </Router>
       );
    };

  // It's simple store your history in a variable and make use of it
```

Comment: The question is about how to redirect users from old hash links to new ones (without the hash)

Comment: can you read the question again, it says how to redirect from hash to browser !!!

Comment: right. but your solution don't redirect user  from url like:  '/#/product/1'   to '/product/1'.
Also author says:
> Users can access the old links with the hash on their bookmarks, email, other sites etc

Comment: ok @Max got it they needed something like location.replace functionality.